# Gnuplot: Parametric plot on top of pm3d map

Tags: gnuplot

I want to plot a 2d pm3d map from a file and then add a curve on top of it. I tried

```
set pm3d map
set parametric
fx(t) = r*cos(t)
fy(t) = r*sin(t)
plot fx(t),fy(t) w l, 'GapRM.dat' u 1:2:3 w pm3d
```

but then I get the error message

```
Too many using specs for this style
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple way. In this example a plot an ellipse on top of a 3d map:

```
set parametric
set view map
set urange [0:6.281]
set vrange [0:2*pi]
set xrange [-6:6]
set yrange [-6:6]
splot 'file.dat' using 1:2:3 w pm3d, 2*cos(u),3*sin(u),0 ls 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can mix parametric with pm3d, but I doubt (your example doesn't work because you need a splot to use a pm3d).

I suggest to plot to a temporary file the parametric stuff and then load it on top of the pm3d.

something like this:

```
set table "tmpfile.dat"
set parametric
fx(t) = r*cos(t)
fy(t) = r*sin(t)
plot fx(t),fy(t) w l
unset table
unset parametric
set pm3d map
splot x**2 w pm3d, 'tmpfile.dat' u 1:2:(0) w l lc palette
```